# Pin: instrument a specified shared library

Tags: x86, instrumentation, intel-pin, dynamic-analysis

I am performing some simple instrumentation task on an executable file and its related shared libraries, recording all the executed instructions in the main file as well as the shared libraries.

However, `Pin` always throw

```
Pin is out of memory: MmapChecked
```

During the instrumentation. Since I am working on a 32-bit system, every time it reaches to around 3G memory consumption, the instrumentation process will crash.

I would like to work on this 32-bit system, since there are quite a lot of shared libraries on this platform. On the other hand, because actually I am only interested in **one** shared library, so I am thinking to find a way to only record the executed instructions inside the main executable as well as that special library.

However, I have no idea whether/how to do that. Right now before instrumentation, my setting is:

```
PIN_LockClient();
IMG img = IMG_FindByAddress(INS_Address(ins));
PIN_UnlockClient();

// if (IMG_Valid(img) && IMG_IsMainExecutable(img)){
if (IMG_Valid(img)) {           <--------------------- this line
    INS_InsertCall(ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)insCallBack,
                   IARG_BOOL,
                   IARG_ADDRINT, INS_Address(ins),
                   IARG_PTR, new string(INS_Disassemble(ins)),
                   IARG_CONTEXT,
                   IARG_ADDRINT, INS_NextAddress(ins),
                   IARG_END);

}
```

As you can see, I didn't check whether I am instrumenting the main executable or not, which means I should be able to instrument all the libraries.

My test platform is 32-bit x86 Ubuntu 14.04. And the test target is 32-bit ELF binary code.

So my question is: given my situation, should I configure to only instrument my interested library in order to overcome the memory exception? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: IIRC, 32-bit processes can use the full 4GiB of virtual address space if running under a 64-bit kernel.  You can use a 64-bit kernel with a 32-bit user-space.  (Specifically, a 32-bit install of Ubuntu should still boot if you replace the kernel with a 64-bit kernel.  Ubuntu probably even packages one, but I forget.  32-bit has been obsolete for ~10 years)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use IMG_Name to get the file name as pin sees it and compare it to the shared object of interest. InstLib provides a drop-in implementation of this but it's easy to do on your own.